# Why Azure B2C removes color property for mask-icon favicon

Tags: safari, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using custom policies and custom html in Azure B2C which is all working well except for the favicon on Safari (only).

My head includes the link for safari pinned-tabs

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/b2cweb/safari-pinned-tabs-favicon.svg" color="red">
```

However, when run the dev tools show for the Azure B2C SignUp/In

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/b2cweb/safari-pinned-tabs-favicon.svg">
```

hence the color property was stripped away.

Is this a bug and how can it be fixed?
Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Octopus and it seems Link tag with color attribute has known issue and please follow this document - https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2230

Comment: This is also Azure B2C related because the mask-icon works properly on github.